# Are property taxes prorated per quarter or per fiscal year at closing?

Tags: real-estate, property-taxes, massachusetts

We just closed on a property last week, and were surprised to see that property taxes were prorated for only the quarter in which the closing happened (Q3), and not for the full fiscal year.

Our closing agent won't respond our inquiries, hence my asking here:

1) Is it common practice to prorate taxes for just a quarter instead of for the full fiscal year?

2) If yes, what if there is a huge discrepancy between preliminary and actual taxes? (Let's say Q1 and Q2 tax bill is 1.000,- each, but Q3 (in which the closing happened) and Q4 is 3.000,- each.)

FYI - this concerns a new construction in Massachusetts, where property taxes are paid quarterly in advance; fiscal year is 7/1 - 6/30; Q1 and Q2 bill preliminary taxes, Q3 and Q4 actual taxes.

Thank you!

Comment: Did the tax assessment change between Q1/Q2 and Q3/Q4 because the improvement (the new construction mentioned) was finished, or for some other reason?

Comment: yes to the former. the assessment was done in Jan 2019, but the preliminary taxes for Q1/Q2 are based on the previous year. then, in Q3/Q4 the rest is due as actual taxes.